# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'minValue не может быть больше maxValue.'

Tags: c#

Только учусь программированию и столкнулся с вот такой проблемой:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'minValue не может быть больше
>   maxValue.'

```
private void UpdateMole()
{
     _mole.Update(
        rnd.Next(Resources.giohead.Width, this.Width - Resources.giohead.Width),
        rnd.Next(this.Height / 2, this.Height - Resources.giohead.Height * 2)
        );
}
```

UPD Нужно было убрать `*2` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно, что в одном из методов `Random.Next(min, max)` первое значение получается больше второго. Поставь точку остановки в студии (прогугли как) на моменте где выбивает ошибку и посмотри, какие у тебя значения там получаются.